# Infinite dimensional symmetric operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm a physicist and in one of my derivation I am using a relation which I simply generalized from the finite dimensional case and I wanted to confirm that this makes sense in the infinite as well. The relation is the following. Say you have a function $B(x,y)$ that is symmetric $B(x,y) = B(y,x)$. Does the following relation hold
\begin{equation*}
   \int dy dz \; \delta(x-z) B(x,y) f(y)=\int dy dz \; \delta(x-y)B(x,z) f(y),
\end{equation*}
where $f(y)$ is just a function.
I realize that this use of delta functions is a bit unorthodox. I just want to know if such a relation can make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, where these integrals makes sense, they can be written as iterated integrals: for the left hand side,
$$
\iint dy\,dz\, \delta(x - y)B(x,y)f(y) = \\
\int dy\left[\int dz \,\delta(x - z) B(x,y) f(y)\right] = \\
\int dy\,B(x,y)f(y).
$$
For the right hand side,
$$
\iint dy\,dz \,\delta(x-y)B(x,z)f(y) = \\
\int dz\,\int dy\,\delta(x - y)B(x,z) f(y) = \\
\int dz\,B(x,z) f(x) = \\
f(x) \int dz\,B(x,z).
$$
With the integrals written in this way, I think it is clear that the results will not be equal.

As a counterexample, though, consider
$$
B(x,y) = e^{-x^2 - y^2}, \quad f(x) = x.
$$
The first integral yields the result zero because $\int dy\,B(x,y)f(y)$ is an integral of an odd function. The second integral results in $f(x)g(x)$, where $f$ is as above and $g(x) = \int dz\,B(x,z) = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-x^2}$ is non-zero for all $x$.